# Travelling by Kuwait Airways - Travel restrictions

Tags: kuwait

I booked a flight through Kuwait Airways, in a hurry. They have a transit through Kuwait city. The flight is from India to New York. I already have a student visa for the US.
I am not sure if the trump travel ban will have any impact. Probably not since it is only a transit.
Will I be able to carry my laptop on the cabin? There was some restriction a little while ago, but I think it has been lifted now. Will it be alright if I do not switch it on even if the rules change again?
Finally, there was some news about travel emargo around Kuwait, by Middle eastern countries. Is the risk too much to cancel my flight and book another one?

Thank you so much. Really regretting this right now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You'll be fine**.  All laptop bans have been lifted now, and the embargo is for Qatar, not Kuwait.

Comment: Ah right, sorry yes that was Qatar. What can i do if laptop ban comes into play again? Was that only for switching on laptops?

Comment: The airlines in question have already implemented the extra security measures requested by the US, so it's very unlikely the restrictions will be restored.